# Why Some Bootstrap Class and CSS property is not working in my code?

Tags: html, properties, font-family, bootstrap-5, lead

Here I wanted to make a website template through **BOOTSTRAP** and **CSS**.But in my code some ***bootstrap class is not working*** like **lead,font-weight,color,bg-color** etc.If I use some bootstrap text-color in a section than when I use some other color in css in the same section ,I doesn't work. I want to use same font-family over every text.But if I use font family,than lead class doesn't work.In the same way,bootstrap font-weight-bold/bolder is working but light/lighter is not working not even in CSS,What can I do in this situation?

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!--ALL LINK-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/ia_100000000.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
    <title>AppAmp Health Tracker Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="section bg-light py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col h1">
        Our Team and History
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-xl-6 lead section1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis perspiciatis vero accusantium excepturi aperiam eius sit quis nobis cupiditate voluptatem tempora a odio, ad, officiis ex harum saepe fuga at modi quibusdam voluptas voluptatum!</div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 lead font-weight-lighter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis perspiciatis vero accusantium excepturi aperiam eius sit quis nobis cupiditate voluptatem tempora a odio, ad, officiis ex harum saepe fuga at modi quibusdam voluptas voluptatum!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
p,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,a,blockquote,i,button,li,div{
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}
.section1{
  font-weight:400;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your font family does not support light or lighter font weights, it will not render light text. It is about font family. You should add supported font weights to link

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

On the other hand, i tried the following text classes from bootstrap and it is working.

```
<div class="col-xl-6 lead section1 text-danger">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Debitis perspiciatis vero <span class="text-warning">accusantium</span> 
    excepturi aperiam eius sit quis nobis cupiditate voluptatem tempora a 
    odio, ad, officiis ex harum saepe fuga at modi quibusdam voluptas 
    voluptatum!
</div>
```

And it is a working pen: https://codepen.io/umutcakirbm/pen/KKaqwVp

**EDIT:**

Lead class has this properties

```
.lead {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 300; // it will not work 
}
```

If you give extra font-weight-lighter/bolder/light etc. , it will override it because it has `!important` attribute.

And also `text-*` classes has `!important` attribute so you should add `!important` at your own css to override text class. Like this;

```
<span class="text-warning" style="color: #000 !important;">accusantium</span>
```

Comment: bootstrap text color woks but when i use  a textcolor in css and some other color in bootstrap then boostrap color works but i want to give priority to css...and why lead class is not working??

Comment: I edited my answer and codepen, you can check again.

Answer (score 0):

I was working today to use custom CSS with [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) and some of the CSS properties do work but some of them were not working correctly or Not Working. After juggling some time, I use **`!important`** at the end of the property in CSS, It Worked for me.

The **`!important`** rule in CSS is used to add more importance to a property/value than normal.

In fact, if you use the **`!important`** rule, it will **override ALL previous styling rules** for that specific property on that element!

Wants to know more about **`!important`**? [Click Here to See on W3School.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp#:%7E:text=important%3F-,The%20!,specific%20property%20on%20that%20element!)

```
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Best Regards, 
 **Ahmed Iqbal B.**